# Docker container file doesn't import

Tags: docker, mariadb

I did on one machine

```
$ docker export mymariadb | gzip > mymariadb.gz
```

then I copied it to another machine (Windows) unpacked it and did

```
> docker import mymariadb
sha256:<HASH>
```

Unfortunately, I don't see `mymariadb` container in `docker ps -a`.

If I do

```
> docker run mymariadb
```

it says image doesn't exist neither locally nor in repo.

What I did wrong?

Comment: Are you exporting the container from linux machine and importing it on windows machine?

Comment: Exactly what I do

Comment: I tried linux to linux too, with the same result

Comment: Using `docker export` at all is really unusual; if you have a database container based on a Docker Hub image, I don't think its export will include its data, which is what you're actually after.  What's your higher-level goal; why can't you just `docker run` a new container on the target system?

Comment: @DavidMaze in Oracle VirtualBox I was able to clone virtual machine with all it's state. Isn't it possible with docker?

Comment: @DavidMaze what did I do with my commands?

Comment: Docker doesn't work that way.  A container is much more like a wrapper around a single process than a full VM.  When you shut down your laptop, you don't take a snapshot of your browser; instead, you start a new browser application when you start up again.  Containers generally work the same way.

Comment: @DavidMaze okay but what is the purpose of `export` command then?